# unite the strings of columns in one string

Tags: r

I want to unite the texts of columns in one string , I am trying like this but not working for me

```
df <- data.frame(A1 = c("class","type","class","type","class","class","class","class","class"),
                 B1 = c("b2","b3","b3","b1","b3","b3","b3","b2","b1"),
                 C1 = c(22,56,43,56,1,5,7,8,NA),
                 C1T=c(NA,  "Part of other business",   NA, NA, NA, NA, "temprorary", NA, NA))
```

the output should be like
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this dynamically or in a function -

```
library(dplyr)

var1 <- "C1T"
group_byy <- "B1" 

df %>%
  group_by(.data[[group_byy]]) %>%
  summarise(Texts = toString(na.omit(.data[[var1]]))) %>%
  filter(Texts != '')

#  B1    Texts                             
#  <chr> <chr>                             
#1 b3    Part of other business, temprorary
```

Comment: I have tried this but giving extra comma before string      Texts<- df %>%
  group_by(!!group_byy )%>% 
  summarise(Texts = toString(coalesce(!!var1 ),collapse = " "))%>% 
  select(-!!group_byy ) %>% unlist() %>% gsub(c("NA",","),"", .)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want to do this for all the columns or only C, for all the columns you could do

```
> sapply(df,function(x){paste0(na.omit(x),collapse=",")})

                                                   A1 
"class,type,class,type,class,class,class,class,class" 
                                                   B1 
                         "b2,b3,b3,b1,b3,b3,b3,b2,b1" 
                                                  C1T 
                  "Part of other business,temprorary"
```

Comment: I am trying like this but not getting expecting output:    var1 <- "C1T"
var1 <- rlang::parse_expr(var1)
group_byy <- "B1"
group_byy <- rlang::parse_expr(group_byy)

Texts <- df %>% select(!!group_byy, !!var1) %>% 
  group_by(!!group_byy) %>% summarise(Comments=toString(!!var1),collapse = " ") %>% 
  select(Comments) %>% unlist() %>% gsub("NA","", .) %>% 
  stringi::stri_trim_both()

Comment: To make it like the data frame you showed, just add data.frame() argument like so:
data.frame(text=sapply(df,function(x){paste0(na.omit(x),collapse=",")}))

Answer (score 1):

You could try this code:
It removes all NA rows. then after grouping use `summarise` with `toString()`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%  
    drop_na() %>%  
    group_by(B1 )%>%
    summarise(Texts = toString(C1T)) %>% 
    select(-B1)
```

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  Texts                             
  <chr>                             
1 Part of other business, temprorary
```